# margin point of view of logistic regression

Tags: logistic, lasso, high-dimensional

I am currently studying Lasso for logistic regression and am using Buhlmann et.al book (Statistics for High Dimensional Data) to understand better. 
 Section 
In this book on page 3.3.1 they define the margin point of view of logistic regression. Does anyone knows how to get this?

Thanks